# NullPointException while uploading file in spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I try to upload a *.csv* file's data into database, but when i upload and submit it, it throws ***nullpointexception***. Means, when I print *name* in controller, *name* is printed, but when i try to get the file, it show *null*.

**FileUpload model class**

```
public class FileUpload {
    private CommonsMultipartFile[] files;   
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "uploadPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView uploadPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("upload_page");
        FileUpload formUpload = new FileUpload();
        model.addObject("formUpload", formUpload);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doUpload(@ModelAttribute("formUpload") FileUpload fileUpload, BindingResult result) throws IOException, JAXBException {

        System.out.println("myfirl "+fileUpload.getFiles());  // output is null
        System.out.println("name "+fileUpload.getName());  // name is displaying

        //other stuffs

}
```

*upload_page*

```
<spring:url value="/doUpload" var="doUploadURL"/> 
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="formUpload" action="${doUploadURL }" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <form:input path="files" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
     <form:input path="name" type="text"/>    
     <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form:form>
```

**WebConfig**

```
@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(20*1024*1024);

    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

I tried to sort it out in many ways, but failed. Anyone try to sort it out? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the interface `MultipartFile` instead of the concrete type `CommonsMultipartFile` in your model object. Also you should use a list instead of an array (if memory serves me well).

Comment: still it shows null, my problem is, controller does not get the file @deinum

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println(file.getName);
        }
}
```

or you can do that

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFileHandler(MultipartHttpServletRequest  request) {
            Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
            while (itr.hasNext()){
               System.out.println(itr.next().toString());
            }
....
    }
```